# How to apply a scale to an extent with OpenLayers?

Tags: printing, openlayers, scale

I make some development with OpenLayers 5.3 and the print plugin. I'm able to generate a printing according to a feature and its extent, the extent of the feature becomes the bbox for the printing, it works well.

Now, I would like to be able to generate the same printing, but according a scale, for example 1:20000, 1:10000, 1:5000, 1:2500... I guess I have to start from the center of the extent of the feature, but what are the next formulas to generate a new extent for my printing that will follow the asked scale ?

I found this sample but I can't get the expected result, I'm surely messing up in the calculations : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60752/calculating-bounding-box-by-given-center-and-scale-in-android

What is the way to generate an extent for a given scale with OpenLayers 5 ?

Many thanks !

Comment: You could try basing it on this OpenLayers 6 example https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/print-to-scale.html

Comment: Thank you very much Mike, I found this solution a little after I have posted my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can send scale parameter directly in the print request with a center, no need to apply formulas to extent. Like this way :

```
pages:[
{
    bbox:[77998.25968363,95207.61960341,78291.41499803,95426.51968283],
    rotation:0,
    ...
```

becomes

```
pages:[
{
    center:[78144.83734083001,95317.06964311999],
    scale:2500,
    useNearestScale: true,
    rotation:0,
    ...
```